# QTreeWidgetItem highlight text problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I tried to display QTreeWidgetItem text with a part highlighted in blue.
As I have see in other post we can use a QLabel and add it as itemWidget.

```
QString("Test<SPAN style='background-color: lightblue'>blue</SPAN>display");
```

The text I use look like that. The text is correctly highlighted but lot of problems appears. I cannot check/uncheck my items and either use drag and drop on a big part of them.

Are there a solution to solve this problem using ItemDelegate or other thing ?
I'm using Qt 5.13

I need your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome. You say you are using a `QLabel` and use it as `QWidgetItem` (`ItemWidget`?) but only provide a single line with a `QString`. Please be sure to include the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question or we won't be able to assist you.

Comment: provide a [MRE]

Comment: auto *tree= new QTreeWidget;
    auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(tree);
    auto *label= new QLabel(QString("Test<SPAN style='background-color: lightblue'>blue</SPAN>display"));
    tree->setItemWidget(0, label);

When I do something like that, I cannot check or uncheck my item anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto *tree= new QTreeWidget;
auto *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(tree);
auto *label= new QLabel(QString("Test<SPAN style='background-color: lightblue'>blue</SPAN>display"));
tree->setItemWidget(0, label);
```

When I do something like that, I cannot check or uncheck my item anymore.